# Jinja2 default value when None

Tags: python, jinja2

I have two variables, `var_a` and `var_b`, `var_a` can be `None` or *empty string*.

Can I use the `or` operator to default to `var_b` when `var_a` is None or empty?

```
{{ var_a or var_b }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep you can use the [none](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#none) test like this:

```
{% if var_a is not none %}   
    {{ var_a }}
{% else %}
    {{ var_b}}
{% endif %}
```